# meta field for numerous links

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox

*I'm currently trying to store something which looks like this.*

```
[links] => array 
    (
        [0] => examplelink.com/RANDOM-MD5
        [1] => examplelink1.com/RANDOM-MD5
        [2] => examplelink2.com/RANDOM-MD5
        [3] => examplelink3.com/RANDOM-MD5
        [4] => examplelink4.com/RANDOM-MD5
        [5] => examplelink5.com/RANDOM-MD5
    )
```

However the tracks field will display a different link in every single post on the website.

Currently, I'm storing every link in a database table and returning it via `the_content` portion and it's extremely messy and in some cases doesn't even actually work properly.

How would I create a meta table for this? And how would I return each result on my automation process page? Cause currently its just storing the array results into a database, and processes the actual post page with something that looks like this.

```
$content = $row['links'];
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( trim( $row['title'] ) ),
      'post_content'  => $content,
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_category' => array(5),
      'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
```

here's an HTML demo of how I would like the links to display on the front end of my website.

```
<ul>
<a href="http://examplelink.com/RANDOM-MD5"><li>Link 1</li></a>
<a href="http://examplelink1.com/RANDOM-MD5"><li>Link 2</li></a>
<a href="http://examplelink1.com/RANDOM-MD5"><li>Link 3</li></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I an not entirely sure that I understood the question but I am guessing you need to publish an array of specific links on each post page.

The best option will be to save the links in a meta field for that post. Note that you can store the links separated by a comma. Something like this:

```
examplelink.com/RANDOM-MD5,examplelink1.com/RANDOM-MD5,examplelink2.com/RANDOM-MD5
```

You can then call this meta field in the single post page using the [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function. Then you can use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function where you can create an array of that comma separated links.

Suppose the custom field you create in your post is "random_links", your code will look something like this:

```
$post_links = get_post_meta(<your_post_id>,'random_links',TRUE);
$link_array = explode(" ", $post_links);
```

$link_array will have your array of the links you added. To display it in required format use the following code.

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($link_array as $single_link) {?>
<a href="<?php echo $single_link; ?>"><li>Link 1</li></a>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

This will print the list in an unordered list.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: With this method it will display every result as **link one**?

Comment: No.. this will add an unordered list of links like you asked for in your question. If you need single link you can skip the "explode" & "foreach" functions.